# Shortest path of weighted and directed graph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, shortest-path, neo4j-apoc

I created a map of city in Neo4j using OpenStreetMap and OpenAddresses data. I want to find the shortest path from one address to another. The problem is that, when I'm using function apoc.algo.aStarConfig,I'm getting a path without consideration about direction of a relationship.

```
MATCH (a:Address)-[:NEAREST_INTERSECTION]->(source:Intersection)
WHERE a.full_address CONTAINS "410 E 5TH AVE SAN MATEO, CA"
MATCH (poi:Address)-[:NEAREST_INTERSECTION]->(dest:Intersection) 
WHERE poi.full_address CONTAINS "39 GRAND BLVD SAN MATEO, CA"
CALL apoc.algo.aStarConfig(source, dest, "ROAD_SEGMENT", 
  {pointPropName: "location", weight: "length"}) 
YIELD weight, path
RETURN *
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTytn.png)

**So my question is if there is a possibility to find the shortest path from one path to another not consider upstream relathionships?**

Comment: This has nothing to do with your main question, but don't you want to use `STARTS WITH` instead of `CONTAINS`? With `CONTAINS` you would match numeric street addresses that happen to end with the desired digits and the match might be slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only find paths where the relationships are in one direction e.g. outbound, you can either prepend `<` to the relationship type for inbound, or append `>` for outbound.

To only follow outbound `ROAD_SEGMENT` relationships, your query would become:

```sql
MATCH (a:Address)-[:NEAREST_INTERSECTION]->(source:Intersection)
WHERE a.full_address CONTAINS "410 E 5TH AVE SAN MATEO, CA"
MATCH (poi:Address)-[:NEAREST_INTERSECTION]->(dest:Intersection) 
WHERE poi.full_address CONTAINS "39 GRAND BLVD SAN MATEO, CA"
CALL apoc.algo.aStarConfig(source, dest, "ROAD_SEGMENT>", 
  {pointPropName: "location", weight: "length"}) 
YIELD weight, path
RETURN *
```